# How to make certain Button Label subview not tappable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I will show very simplified example. Is it possible to make `Circle()` be not tappable without shifting Circle() from the button label, so the action doesn't execute if I press on the circle. There are many certain reasons I need it this way.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button (action: {}
        ) {
            HStack {
                
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 80)
                    
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
           
            
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `.disabled(true)` and `.allowsHitTesting(false)` but it didn't work. If it is not possible, please let me know

Comment: Why did you put the `HStack` as the button label if you only want the `Text` to be tappable? Sounds like only the `Text` should be the button label. i.e. `HStack { Circle() Button {} label: { Text(...) } }`

Comment: that's why I said "There are many certain reasons I need it this way". It's a long story to explain, this is just a very simple example

Comment: You don't need to explain your actual long story. Just show a situation where what I suggested wouldn't work.

Comment: can you tell me if it is possible or not exactly the way I show? Your suggestion of course would work, that's what anyone would use

Comment: Well I told you it's possible "exactly the way you show". Just put the `HStack` on the outside. And you apparently didn't want to do that. I can suggest some more ways, but who knows whether you will again not want to do that. Please explain what the actual situation is like.

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible to make certain button label subview not tappable.

Comment: You can add `.highPriorityGesture(LongPressGesture())` to the circle. Not only is it a nasty hack, if you also actually want the circle to have some other gesture, this wouldn't work, and the back-and-forth between us would go on and on. This sounds like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), please explain why you need to do this. There might be a better way to do what you *actually* want to do.

Comment: Instead of using a button, you could use `.onTapGesture`. Would that work for you? I can give an example of that if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your specific question, one way of preventing taps to the circle from causing the button to be activated is to have a dummy button in an overlay over the circle. This then consumes all gestures that would otherwise activate the button below. Like this:

```swift
Button {
    print("button tapped")
} label: {
    HStack {
        Button {
            print("do nothing")
        } label: {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 80)
        }

        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

If you could elaborate on exactly why you would want to do this, maybe a better solution could be suggested.

Comment: If you press on the button long enough, then release the finger, the button's action will still be triggered. The button's action triggers *on touch up*, not on a tap gesture. Probably better to use a `LongPressGesture`, which is not an "instant" gesture, and starts on touch down.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, you were right about the long press. Answer updated to use a dummy Button in an overlay, instead of an onTapGesture on the circle.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer since it answers the question with the way it was formulated, by the way I dont think you need overlay, I think you can wrap circle itself inside second Button